# Install pgadmin III for a linked database container in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

There are two running docker containers. One container containing a web application and the second is a linked postgres database.

Where should the Pgadmin III tool be installed?

Comment: Why not put it in its own container?  Isn't that what containers are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgAdmin` [can be deployed](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html)
 in a container using the image at [hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/)

E.g. to run a `TLS` secured container using a shared config/storage directory in `/private/var/lib/pgadmin` on the host, and servers pre-loaded from `/tmp/servers.json` on the host:

```
docker pull dpage/pgadmin4
docker run -p 443:443 \
    -v /private/var/lib/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin \
    -v /path/to/certificate.cert:/certs/server.cert \
    -v /path/to/certificate.key:/certs/server.key \
    -v /tmp/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json \
    -e 'PGADMIN\_DEFAULT\_EMAIL=user@domain.com' \
    -e 'PGADMIN\_DEFAULT\_PASSWORD=SuperSecret' \
    -e 'PGADMIN\_ENABLE\_TLS=True' \
    -d dpage/pgadmin4
```